# Is it possible to zip an Android JUnit Test suite into a JAR file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit, robotium

I have a suite of Android JUnit tests written using robotium, and for ease of use for others I'd like to zip it into a JAR file. But I've been having issues with getting it into a JAR file, which has me thinking it might not be possible. I've tried to zip it into a runnable jar file, but the option is not available for me (the class does not appear on the list of classes I can turn into a jar).

What I've done is write a Java program that uses Robotium, which runs on a desktop and sends an APK to run tests on an APK on an android device, then reports back results to the desktop. It runs on the android device, but it's through the desktop.

Is it possible, and if not, is there another way to do it?

Comment: Apparently I don't understand what you are asking. Can you please provide more details about the structure of this program that you are trying to package into a JAR file?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What error are you getting? 
What is the command that are you using to jar them?

Comment: Also, what option isn't available for you? Where are you looking for this option?

Comment: Basically, I've written a suite of JUnit tests using a tool called robotium. It's written in Java just like one would write JUnit tests. When I run the program in eclipse, the tests are sent to the android device I have plugged into the computer. The tests are run on an application on the phone, and results come back and are displayed like normal JUnit tests.

Comment: Basically, I try to export my project as a runnable jar file, and then I get a dropdown list of classes in my workspace. Every class appears except my classes with the tests, I think because they're Android JUnit Tests instead of a Java application. Either I'm not doing something right, I have to modify something in order to run the JUnit tests as a java application, or it's just impossible.

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear on exactly what you are trying to package in the JAR file? Are you trying to package a Java SE app or Android JUnit tests or some of both? How have you tried packaging these? Please give the details of the steps you take and what happens when you do them.

Comment: You say "every class appears except my classes with the tests"? What classes are included in "every class"?

Comment: I'm trying to package the tests I've written. So I could send the jar file to others and then they could run the tests from their computer on their android devices. I've tried packaging it by exporting it from eclipse as a runnable jar file. When I say every class appears, I mean every class from every project in my workspace except for these ones.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do is give someone the apk of your tests, within eclipse if you look inside the bin folder you will see a file named after your project with a .apk extension. This is the file that contains all your tests in the correct format.

If you give someone this apk they can install it on there device and then using adb run a command to run the tests. The actual format of the command depends on your package neames etc, more information about it can be found AT http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#AMSyntax but will basically look like

```
adb shell am instrument -w <package.test>/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

You can also install the apk file etc from the command line using adb which you can find out how to do http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#move adb is pretty handy for android testing.

Comment: Here's what I get in the console when running this. INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: Component
Info{com.isoftstone.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.isoftstone.test/andro
id.test.InstrumentationTestRunner

Comment: And you installed the Apk of both your application and tests?